# Is there any tool available to test webRTC application on different devices,network and platform

Tags: webrtc

I build one website where I used webRTC for video calling.I want to ensure that webRTC will work on different devices and network smoothly.I used **stun:stun.services.mozilla.com** and **stun:stun.l.google.com:19302** this two stun server which is free. So I want to ensure that I will work with all type of networks and devices.

Comment: Um, the browser? Btw. STUN only works in about 60%-70% of cases. You'll need a TURN server for the remainder.

Comment: you can use something like this:
https://test.webrtc.org/